# ($C^1$ Function)False or true? (justify) a) Let $f: X \to \mathbb R$. If $f'(x) = 0, \forall x \in X$, then $f'$ is constant...

Tags: derivatives, solution-verification, problem-solving, constants

> False or true? (justify)

> a) Let $f: X \to \mathbb R$. If $f'(x) = 0, \forall x \in X$, then $f(x)$ is constant.

> b) If $f$ is differentiable, then $f$ is of class $C^1$. In the case of true prove, in the case of false, provide an example.

a) True, f is derivable when $f'(a) = \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x) – f(a)}{x-a}$ is a function and constant if and only if its derivative is equal to zero at all points in the range. As from the statement we have that $f'(x) =0$ for all x belonging to X, so X is constant.

b) False. $f(x) = x^2 sin (\frac{1}{x^2})$, if $x \ne 0$ and $0$ if $x = 0$.

I know a is true and b is false but I'm not sure if I've shown this properly.

Thank's for any help.

Comment: a) is true if X is an interval.

Comment: According to *what you’ve written*, $f'$ is identically zero, and thus constant.

Comment: is a supposed to be $f'$ is constant or $f$ is constant?  The former is trivial,   the latter is only true if an interval, as in the comment and answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) is False.

Let $$X=(-\infty,0)\cup (0,+\infty)$$

and $ f $ defined at $ X $,  by

$$(\forall x<0)\;\; f(x)=-1$$
and
$$(\forall x>0)\;\;f(x)=1$$

$ f $ is differentiable at $ X $ and

$$(\forall x\in X)\;\; f'(x)=0$$
But $ f $ is not constant.

b) is also false. Your counterexample is good.